# PhantomJS Getting Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

If I have this:

```
<video data-autostart="false" data-src="http://example.com/1.mp4">
```

I get the error below:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object

Below is my JavaScript code:

```
var page = require( 'webpage' ).create();
    var url = 'http://example.com/';
    page.open(url, function( status ) {
        if ( status === 'success' ) {
        page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js', function() {
            var link = page.evaluate(function() {
                return $( 'video[data-autostart="false"]' ).attr( 'data-src' );
            });
            console.log( link );
            phantom.exit();
        });
    } else {
        console.log( 'FAIL' );
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing almost everything right, but the element you're looking for apparently doesn't exist when you access it in the script.

Therefore the error, undefined is not an object. The element you try to access is undefined, doesn't exist.

You could check that an element is there before accessing it:

```
var link = page.evaluate(function() {
    if($( 'video[data-autostart="false"]' ).length != 0)
    {
        return $( 'video[data-autostart="false"]' ).attr( 'data-src' );
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
});

if (link === false) {
    console.log("Video not found!");
    phantom.exit(1); // Error exit code
}
```

The complete working example:

```
var url = "http://html5demos.com/video";
var page = require( 'webpage' ).create();

page.open(url, function( status ) {
    if ( status === 'success' ) {
        page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js', function() {
            var link = page.evaluate(function() {
                if($( 'video' ).length != 0)
                {
                    return $( 'video' ).attr('preload');
                }

            });
            console.log( link );
            phantom.exit();
        });
    } else {
        console.log( 'FAIL' );
    }
});
```

Prints

> metadata